# What's in ~/.config/google-chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, disk-usage

It uses more than 100 MB on my tiny system, I can't really imagine this all just being the configuration of only the chrome browser. How would I reduce its size?

Comment: Lucky you. I came to this question trying to understand why it's taking 3.7GB on my SSD.

Comment: upon verification, it was a buggy extension taking most of that space.

Comment: @igorsantos07, can you please share - which extension? having the same issue

Comment: I have a bunch, and you probably do as well. Use the Disk Usage Analyzer (or similar utility) to check the chrome folders. Then, you look for the extension code (something like `~google-chrome/extensions/9iedfdmgefmgoefm` and look for it in the extensions page.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Chromium projects site](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) it's where the users data directory is. So beyond the configuration it will contain the History, bookmarks, cookies, extensions etc.

To minimise the disk usage, you can uninstall extensions you no longer use and get Chrome to clear it's cache/history.

Comment: Clearing out cookies and history reduced the size by roughly 50%. That's something, but still more than 50MB remain. The cache lives in `~/.cache/google-chrome/`, I had already emptied that out before, so I was surprised to see the `.config` folder us so much disk space.

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration directory of google-chrome. It contains some user data, history, cookies,extensions and bookmarks, crash reports, application cache and safe browsing data...

To know what is consuming your disk storage you can use:

```
du -h ~/.config/google-chrome
```

So you can check which directory/file is consuming your disk storage.